# Is there a way to dynamically change variables depending on length of list

Tags: python, variables

May seem like a silly question is there any way to create variables depending on the number of objects in a list. The context to this is I am trying to create an n body simulation. One in which the user can manually chose the planets they want in the solar system and then run the script with only those planets. So prior to them running the chosing the planets and running the script I will not know how many variables to create. This problem of how many variables to create is show by:
The mass is created by a class objects:
class Objects():

```
position = np.full((1, 3), 0)
velocity = np.full((1, 3), 0)
acceleration = np.full((1, 3), 0)
name = ""
mass = np.full((1, 1), 0)

planets_init = np.full((1, 3), 0)

def __init__(self, Name, Mass, initPosition, initVelocity, initAcceleration):

    au = 149597870.700e3
    v_factor = 1731460

    self.name = Name
    self.mass = Mass
```

The function is solved by using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp by:

```
three_body_sol = sci.integrate.solve_ivp(fun=Objects.ThreeBodyEquations,t_span=domain,y0=init_params,args=(G,planets_mass,N), max_step=max_step)
```

Where the function is:

```
def ThreeBodyEquations(t,w,G,mass,N):
    # N being the number of objects in the system so in this case 2
    m1, m2 = mass

    #Unpack all the variables from the array "w"
    r1=w[:3]
    r2=w[3:6]
    v1=w[6:9]
    v2=w[9:12]
  
    # Harry's attempt
    G = G
    planets_pos = np.vstack((r1, r2))
    planets_mass = mass # np.vstack((m1, m2))

    # positions r = [x,y,z] for all particles
    x = planets_pos[:,0:1]
    y = planets_pos[:,1:2]
    z = planets_pos[:,2:3]


    # matrix that stores all pairwise particle separations: r_j - r_i
    dx = x.T - x
    dy = y.T - y
    dz = z.T - z

    # matrix that stores 1/r^3 for all particle pairwise particle separations
    inv_r3 = (dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)

    inv_r3[inv_r3>0] = inv_r3[inv_r3>0]**(-1.5)

    ax = G * (dx * inv_r3) @ planets_mass
    ay = G * (dy * inv_r3) @ planets_mass
    az = G * (dz * inv_r3) @ planets_mass

    # planets_acceleration = np.sqrt(ax**2 + ay**2 + az**2)
    planets_acceleration = np.vstack((ax,ay,az))
    planets_acceleration = planets_acceleration.flatten()

    dv1bydt=planets_acceleration[0::N]
    dv2bydt=planets_acceleration[1::N]
    # print(planets_acceleration)
    dr1bydt=v1
    dr2bydt=v2

    #Package the derivatives into one final size-18 array
    r12_derivs=np.concatenate((dr1bydt,dr2bydt))
    r_derivs = r12derivs    
    v12_derivs=np.concatenate((dv1bydt,dv2bydt))
    v_derivs= v12_derivs
    derivs=np.concatenate((r_derivs,v_derivs))
    return derivs
```

My main question centres around this function. When the user defines what planets they want to use I have no idea what the number of planets will be. I know the range which is might be but that’s all. Is there a feasible way to do this or is this a lost cause?

I hope this clarifys the question with some additional code. Sorry about the previous lack of code its, I didn’t realise it was valuable at first and didn’t want to burden with too much code.

Comment: The rest of the script is very relevant!  It's not really feasible to write code with a dynamic number of named variables, but if we could see how you're using the named variables `m1, m2, m3` it'd be easy to show you how to accomplish the same thing (probably much more easily!) by operating directly on the `mass` list.  Python has very pleasant, simple semantics for performing operations on lists of objects that make it almost as easy as operating on a single object.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, no, it is not advisable. How are you going to work with these dynamically created variables? By dynamically accessing them. However, dynamic access is already provided by lists and dictionaries without any uncommon workarounds. Just stick with the initial list of masses.

Comment: In other words: if you just store the planets in a list `m`, you can already access them as `m[0]`, `m[1]` and so on.

Comment: @Samwise ah ok, apologies for that I seemed to think that it wouldn't be relevant, I'm going to rewrite and update the question.

Comment: Can you please clarify your exact problem? There is a lot of unrelated flavor text and code, that makes it very hard to pinpoint the issue. Specifically, it looks as if you don't even use the individual masses after unpacking them to individual variables. Be aware that the class definition is at best wrongly formatted, at worst incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a function that calculates the mass first, such as

```
      mass = 0
      for planet in planet_list:
            mass = mass+ planet.mass
      return mass

total_mass = calculate_combined_mass([earth, Mars, jupiter] )

three_body_equations(t,w,G,total_mass,N)
```